# In MySQL is there some way to calculate average with a list of numbers?

Tags: mysql, function, select, average

I would like to do something like the following:

```
SELECT AVG([1,2,3]);
```

This would of course return 2. The closest I've got is the following which is less than ideal but can be put in one line:

```
drop table nums;
create temporary table nums (num int);
insert into nums(num) values(1),(2),(3);
select avg(num) from nums;
```

If there's a way I would assume this would also be possible with other functions such as variance() and others.

**Edit**: This idea is out of curiosity not a real problem I need to solve.

Comment: MySQL is not a general purpose programming language, so it prefers things expressed as tables like you have there.

Comment: `select (1+2+3)/3`

Comment: @PaulSpiegel nice... but other functions such as variance() would be hard to produce...

Comment: Perhaps providing more information of what you want to achieve would make it so people provide you a better way of solving your problem? I would suspect you are using the wrong tools.

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius I actually wanted to know the variance() of a list using MySQL but I couldn't figure out how and just got curious... I put avg on the question because it's an easier function.

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with sql, does it?

Answer (score 1):

AVG can only have 1 argument. You'd need to do `SELECT AVG(num) FROM nums`

You could also do `SELECT SUM(num) / COUNT(num) FROM nums`

Just know since you're dividing using ints that it will not be precise.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong tools to solve your problem.

If you want to calculate the variance of a list, use some kind of a scripting language, be it Php, Python, etc. If you want to firstly **store** the data and only **then** calculate the variance, of course, use something like MySql.

Answer (score 0):

I also think that MySQL may not be the right tool (since you didn't want to store the numbers), but the answer to your question is: **yes, you can do it with MySQL** without creating tables if you want.

I didn't find any built-in functions/structures for this, but I came up with the following solution. My idea is to create a custom function which accepts the numbers in a delimited string, then it splits the string and calculates the average of the numbers. Here's an implementation which works with integers. The input should be `num,num,num` and so on, it should end with a number (see the examples at the end).

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS AVGS;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION AVGS(s LONGTEXT) RETURNS DOUBLE
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE sum BIGINT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE count BIGINT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE pos BIGINT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE lft TEXT DEFAULT '';

    -- can we split?
    SET pos = LOCATE(',', s);
    WHILE 0 < pos DO -- while we can split
        SET lft = LEFT(s, pos - 1); -- get the first number
        SET s = SUBSTR(s FROM pos + 1); -- store the rest
        SET sum = sum + CAST(lft AS SIGNED);
        SET count = count + 1;
        SET pos = LOCATE(',', s); -- split again
    END WHILE;

    -- handle last number
    SET sum = sum + CAST(s AS SIGNED);
    SET count = count + 1;

    RETURN sum / count;
END $$
DELIMITER ;

SELECT AVGS("1");     -- prints: 1    
SELECT AVGS("1,2");   -- prints: 1.5
SELECT AVGS("1,2,3"); -- prints: 2
```

See the live working [demo here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ne1aM5XdYTyiUDnipDDRWi/0).

Variance may be much more complex, but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Didn't read the code, I assume it works. Seems like this would be the way to go...